# Getting a URL parameter into the ServiceInterface Service of a C# MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, service, parameters

In my C# MVC app, I can retrieve the URL parameter from my Controller with no problem. But, I'm trying to retrieve the URL parameter from a ServiceInterface Service that is used to retrieve data from the database. The URL parameter is the filter I need for data retrieval.

I've tried:

-Request.RawUrl

-Request.QueryString["s"];      //s is the URL parameter I need

-RouteData.Values

-Request.Params

but everything returns null every time.

What am I doing wrong, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try : Request["parameter1"];

and check parameter spelling

Comment: As soon as I put that in my code, it gives me a syntax error:

"Cannot apply indexing with [ ] to an expression of type 'ServiceStack. ServiceHost.IHttpRequest' "

Answer (score 0):

Well, never could get it to work, or get anyone to give me a good answer that worked.

So, I wrote a cookie instead in the controller and retrieved it in the service. Not a primo solution, but it works